# How to calculate user preference for each location category in Python for a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

The formula for calculating user preference for each location category is given in attached image. The formula is modeled as the weight of each dimension of the feature vector for this type of location.

Fck is the user’s preference of the Ck th location category of type i, and VC(u, r, o) is the number of times that user u has visited location o.

[image]

User preference is to be obtained for Food, Venue, and Entertainment, for different time periods.

We want to denote user preference of user u in time period r of location type i as a feature vector. The user preference profile of a user can be built from his historical data.

e.g

Suppose user Lee has visited locations in the type of “Food” 198 times in
time period 2. The first three location categories of “Food” are
“Sichuan food,” “Hunan food,” and “Jiangzhe food,” and Lee
has been to these categories of locations 32, 26, and 44 times,
respectively. Thus, the preference profile of Lee in time period 2
of type “Food” is  F =< 0.16, 0.13, 0.22, . . . >.

[image]

Please help us with a Python code.

Comment: Why don't you just do it in excel?

Comment: But we want a python code for it

Comment: This website is for you to get help with code that isn't working or advice on what approach to use. Not for people to do your work for you.